# How to escape string/table name in sql insert

Tags: python, mysql

I need to dynamically change the table name based on what environment I'm in. This works:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO exc (_id, md5) VALUES (%(_id)s, %(md5)s)", data)
```

However, what I am trying to do is to dynamically set the table name, for example:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %(table)s (_id, md5) VALUES (%(_id)s, %(md5)s)", data)
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to hard-code the string into there? Doing the above gives me a sql error, even if I put the table name in back-ticks, like:

```
`table_name`
```

How would this be done properly? Note, doing the literal string-formatting of `%` wouldn't be an option here (in that case I'd just write an if statement for each table name possiblity).